# Dynamic site elements not displaying after Django database change

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, pythonanywhere

So I recently changed databases on a Django-based website from SQLite to MySQL.

I did it via dumping the data from the SQLite into a json file and then migrating it to the new MySQL db then loaded it using the `python manage.py loaddata` command.

The site is hosted on pythonanywhere and the tranistion there went flawless, however, on the local copy of the project I have(used to test implementing new features and debug), the dynamic elements on the front page wont load.
I have a dynamic js table with information for various cryptocurrencies.
This is how the head of the table looks on the live site:

[image]

And this is how it looks on the local copy of my machine, with my own hosted MySQL server:

[image]

What I've tried:

- -Collectstatic
- -Running ContentType.objects.all().delete() in python manage.py shell

I also did research on stackoverflow but I could not find a similar issue.
I am also new to Django so it might be something obvious I'm missing

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but just to be sure -- you did use the Django loaddata command to load your fixtures into your local MySQL database as well as into the hosted one, right?

Comment: Yes, I ommited that as I thought it was obvious but thank you for the suggestion nevertheless.

Comment: Cool, I thought that would be the case but it's always worth checking on Stack Overflow -- people sometimes do forget to do the stuff that is obvious to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I used the datadump.json from pythonanywhere rather than my local copy. Also had some issues with the json utf8 encodings so make sure your datadump file is utf8 encoded and/or matches the encoding of your db.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Django fixtures.
[Here is the official link for Django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/)

Comment: This is how I did it it initially. It is not working unfortunately.